# Kubernetes image management for jobs

Tags: kubernetes

How does Kubernetes deal with the resources used by an image when ran in a pod where there are multiple containers running the same image?

If i have an image which is 1gb in size and i run 10 pods with just one container running the same image, how will the memory and resources of the cluster be impacted by running these containers (when they are effectively resting / just running the base image code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each pod is separate and independed from each other. If you run 10 pods with the same image, it will consume 10 times as much resources as a single pod. Doesn't matter they run the same image.

In fact, the only resource pods share is [storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#pod-storage), but only if you specify shared volumes.